# How long to wait before spending wire transfer money?

Tags: india, online-banking, wire-transfer

I made a trade online and someone wire transferred me some money. There's a possibility that the person might reverse the transaction. So how long should i wait before it is confirmed that the money is mine?

Comment: This depends on the country and the type of wire transactions done, varies from few days to few months

Comment: I'm from India, wire was from one bank to another

Comment: Was it NEFT, IMPS, RTGS...

Comment: You say that they might reverse the transaction. How well do you know them? Is there a chance the transaction is a scam? what did you trade?

Comment: NEFT , it was an escrow transaction and i chatted with him for 5 minutes. I don't know anything else about him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEFT transactions can't be reversed by the by the individual. Transfer into  Escrow account depends upon the conditions attached,  your bank should be able to confirm. Escrow accounts are expensive and done for large transactions, in which case please also take the advice of a lawyer